# Correct treatment of quotes in parameter expansions

Tags: ksh, posix, variable-substitution

Using the default value of `IFS`, consider

```
unset var
set -- ${var:-"hello"}
echo "$#"
```

This prints `1` as the parameter expansion expands to the single string `hello`.

```
unset var
set -- "${var:-"hello"}"
echo "$#"
```

This too outputs `1` for the same reason.

However, if using `ksh93`, the following outputs `3` while `dash`, `bash`, `pdksh`, and `zsh` outputs `1`.

```
unset var
set -- "${var:-" hello "}"
echo "$#"
```

In the `ksh93` case, one gets `3` and `"$@"` is two empty strings as `$1` and `$3` while `$2` is the string `hello` with no flanking spaces.  The expanded command seems to be `set -- "" hello ""` in `ksh93` and `set -- " hello "` in other shells.

A related (I believe) issue is

```
unset var
set -- ${var:-""}
echo "$#"
```

which outputs `1` in all `sh`-like shells, except for in `ksh93` where it outputs `0`.  In `ksh93`, the quotes seems to be removed from the empty string before field splitting is performed.

Could the `ksh93` behaviour be explained and supported by how POSIX says that the expansions etc. should be performed?

For the last of the two examples where behaviour between the shells differ, I personally think it's a bug (the command should expand from `set -- ${var:-""}` to `set -- ""`, not to `set --`), but for the first such example (the one with `set -- "${var:-" hello "}"`) I'm not so sure.

---

For testing `ksh93` I'm using "Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01" on OpenBSD 6.4, and also "Version A 2017.0.0-devel-2040-g36a76aca", which is the current development version of the shell.

Comment: IIRC, that was discussed several time on the austin group mailing list. There may even be an austin group bug about it, and the POSIX spec may already have been clarified about that. I can't remember the exact outcome.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas A quick scan through the Austin Group Defect Tracker does not reveal anything related (but I may be using it wrong). It does seem like something that might have been discussed earlier, so if you have a link to this discussion I'd be happy.

Comment: See https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg00174.html

Comment: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=221 probably relevant as well. An older discussion (so not on mail-archive) http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/10868, you may want to use gmane NNTP interface to follow that one.

Comment: `ksh93` creates three arguments: "" hello "", this is why it prints 3. I am not sure whether this is expected...